# How to direct user to new page after edge script completes

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

I'm running an adobe edge animation script when user goes to this page, I would like the page to automatically redirect the user to a new page (first.html) after the edge script completes. If I use window.location.href, no matter where I place it, when the page loads, the edge script doesn't run, it just directs me to the new page. Should I be using a different function? setTimeout maybe? Can't get that to work either.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="index_edgePreload.js"></script>
    <style>
    .edgeLoad-EDGE-132380638 { visibility: hidden; }
    </style>
    <!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->

    </head>
    <body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <div id="Stage" class="EDGE-132380638"> </div>
    </body>
    <script>window.location.href = "first.html";
        </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout works:

```
    <script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "first.html";
    }, 4000);
        </script>
```